# how to get full value of clob while debugging PL SQL script

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, toad, clob

I'm using TOAD editor to write PL/SQL scripts. I cannot see value of a **clob** variable while debugging my script. I tried to add watch to_char(my_clob_variable), bu it didnt work.

Is there a way to see the clob value with toad's features or is there an other way around to do that? (Except updating scripts with **dbms_output** lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while and implemented the PL/SQL solution, but later realized that in Toad you can simply double click on the results grid cell, and it brings up an editor with contents in text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    l_lob CLOB;
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_lob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);

    l_lob := 'Oracle is an American multinational computer technology 
              corporation headquartered in Redwood City, California, United States.';

    IF DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_lob, 6, 1) = 'Oracle' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('... code here ...');
    END IF;

    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(l_lob);
END;
/*
Result:

... code here ...

*/
```